# Create react-app supported in internet explorer 11

Tags: reactjs

How to create react-app in internet explorer 11 using npm package without using CDN and scripts in index.html file. babel polyfil does not work with react new-version.
It opens in chrome and edge but not in internet explorer 11.
Throws error: Object doesn't support property or method 'entries'

Comment: `create-react-app` docs tell you exactly what to do - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/supported-browsers-features/

Comment: I tried it it does not open in internet explorer 11. Can anybody provide a sample code for creating new react app in internet explorer 11

Comment: now I cannot try it myself, but a brief search, some other people report this as a but of the dev packed version while in production build seems to work (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7316) can you try it? (if it work maybe you could use other browsers in dev). as a bottom line, microsoft itself is giving advice to use edge instead of IE (as it is not expected to have any major release, and i guess at some point could be dropped)

Comment: @SagnickBanerjee now that you mention the error, this is a known bug - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8405 - so a temporary solution would involve downgrading to an earlier version until this gets fixed.